# Cakephp custom pagination code

Tags: cakephp

i wan't to create a custom pagination in cakePHP .

I am using  function $paginator->numbers() ; it displays the page numbers like this :

1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ...

but i want first and last buttons and two arrows for next and previous except these numbers 1, 2,3 ,4. For eg:  first <  > last

Answer (score 0):

just configure paginator with these options :-

```
echo $paginator->prev(' previous ', null, null, null);
echo $paginator->next(' next ', null, null, null);
```

For more option please refer to : [Pagination in cakephp](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the pagination output using the helper itself. There are custom methods available to generate links for first, last, next and previous page.

For example, to generate previous page link,

```
echo $this->Paginator->prev(
  ' << ',
  array(),
  null,
  array('class' => 'prev disabled')
);
```

For details, see the doc here: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/helpers/paginator.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use pagination `prev()` & `next()` functions:

```
echo $this->Paginator->first('First Page');
echo $this->Paginator->prev('<');
echo $this->Paginator->next('>');
echo $this->Paginator->last('Last Page');
```

You can read in detail at [CakePHP Pagination](http://api.cakephp.org/2.4/class-PaginatorHelper.html)

Comment: :) he asked for links to first and last page also. I have added that functions in it. see your and other answer.

Comment: Don't mind. I left it so some thing he can do himself.

Comment: can we do like this

first < input box(where we can find any record by id) > last

Comment: for what purpose you are using input box?

Comment: for search purpose.Like i have 100 records and display only one record in html form.So if i want to see 61th record form.Instead of clicking next next direct give the id in the input box and it will take to me that record direct.

Comment: only one record in a HTML form with prefilled values of that id..by feault displaying first record

Comment: Can we do it by ajax?

Comment: Yes definitely its a best method. But particular page must be opened by passing page number in url like "url/page:1". So you need to use window.location('url/page:2') on AJAX request completion